# How can I communicate I am leaving a company to someone I hired who hasn't started?

Tags: team, job-offer, resignation, ethics

Although I am enjoying my current job, I am planning to move to another company as I would like to learn new technology. However, I think that the problem that I am facing now is somewhat ethical. Recently I have interviewed a candidate for my current company and gave an offer. I honestly explained about the job description and I assured him that he will enjoy the job. As part of the interview, I also shared how I am enjoying at my current position etc.,(which is true). It looks like, he is very much interested in the position and I guess that my experiences that I have shared with him also impacted his decision of joining my current company. He accepted the offer and he is going to join in a couple of months. I would be supervising him if he joins my current company.

Actually, I didn't have any ideas of moving to another company while I was interviewing this candidate. This candidate has been in touch with me from the day of the interview. Now, I am almost decided to move to another company (within a month). The following are my options. I request you to please help me to decide.

1. "I would like to call him once I resigned my current job and tell him that I am moving to another company as I am looking for new challenges. However, I would like to tell him that he will enjoy the projects here at my current company."

   I hope that this will give me peace. However, he might share this information to my current company management and I will become bad in their books. It is like burning bridges.
2. "Keep quiet. Don't communicate with him at all about my plans."

   If I do this, he might think that I cheated him etc. I cannot bear these thoughts.

Comment: This exact thing happened to me. After a lot of thinking about it I chose #2, more or less, though I spoke to him personally once my employer was OK with me being public. We still talk, I still have a good relationship with my former employer, and it all worked out well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

People quit all the time. This is part of how businesses work. Hiring managers move around or quit, employees quit, etc. This happens even if people love their jobs. My manager moved to a different position about 2 weeks after I started in my last position, actually.

If the work this new employee was going to do was *so* specific to you personally rather than the position you expect it to change drastically with your departure then I might feel some obligation. Otherwise this is just part of business.

My recommendation would be, when you tell your manager you are resigning, to make sure to indicate you had a new hire who would be starting, etc. Ask if sending an email indicating you  will not be with the company to introduce who they should continue correspondance with. But I wouldn't do this until you have officially told your manager you are resigning.

Comment: I really love the idea of checking in *after* resignation and working it with the new employee as a handoff, not as a heads up.  Way more positive and leaves both the company and the candidate in a good position.

Answer (score 4):

Because the new hire is not going to be able to ask you questions or have a dialog before you leave I would not inform them prior to their starting work.  What I would suggest is that you create a letter welcoming them to the team, explain how you think they will fit in well and enjoy the work they will be doing, apologise for not being there to help them transition but express that you have confidence that they will enjoy working with their new manager.  I would provide this letter in an open envelope to their new manager with a request that it be given to the new hire on their first day.  Leaving the envelope open will allow the new manager to see that you are trying to help smooth the transition, and this should also help ease any guilt you feel.

Comment: I have concerns about this answer. If I were a new employee who had a good relationship with the hiring manager I would probably be miffed about receiving a letter the first day saying they were no longer there. I don't think it would be a deal-breaker for the job, but it would slightly sully the relationship I had with the person. I think, if you do this, maybe doing a follow up email or correspondence a few days later to see how they're liking the new position would be of benefit. It kind of solidifies that you do still have a real interest in them even if you did leave for broader horizons.